# How to check if string contains unwanted characters

Tags: python, bioinformatics

i've been learning Python for only a few weeks, so please bear with me. Let's say I have 3 variables:

```
AX557349 = "gcggatttactcaggggagagcccagataaatggagtctgtgcgtccacagaattcgcacca"
AX557350 = "tccgtgaaacaaagcggatgtaccggatttttattccggctatggggcaattccccgtcgcggagcca"
Tester = "atcgatccblah"

nucs = []
nucs.extend(AX557349, AX557350, Tester)
```

I want to only return list element(s) that contain characters other than "a", "t", "c", or "g". In this case, Tester. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: `return all(c in 'atcg' for c in string_variable)` is the canonical simple way. Better would be to turn into a set so you only have to compare the distinct values: `all(c in set('atcg') for c in set(string_variable))`

Comment: @JonathanGagne P.S. You can use `[mcve]` for a shorthand link to [mcve] in comments on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @iBug How can I found all shortcuts?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting Got it thanks!

Comment: @JonathanGagne Have a look on this page >>>> https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000

Comment: Even better thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help-center [help], in particular "What types of questions should I avoid asking?" [help/dont-ask], and "What topics can I ask about here?" [help/on-topic]. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on Stack Overflow, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Python's [**`any`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) function:

```
if any(c not in set('atcg') for c in Tester):
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways. You can use `all` with a generator expression:

```
def checker(x):
    acgt = set('acgt')
    return not all(i in acgt for i in x)
```

Alternatively, use `set.issubset` or its syntactic sugar `<=`:

```
def checker(x):
    return not set(x) <= set('acgt')
```

Result:

```
checker(AX557349)  # False
checker(AX557350)  # False
checker(Tester)    # True
```

Comment: Converting both strings to sets is inefficient, we only need to know the first character which doesn't match.

Comment: @PeterWood, Sure, that's what my first solution does.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a set?

```
if len(set(Tester) - set("acgt")) > 0:
    print("contains other characters")
```

Comment: What about a boolean test? `if bool(set(Tester) - set("acgt")):`